# Adding Start and End Times from a DateTime Picker in Power Automate Flow

Tags: power-automate

I currently have a Power App that where a leave request can be put in using the DateTime Pickers. I'm trying to create a flow where when the approver presses the approve button those dates will be added to our Vacation Calendar on SharePoint.

I've tried writing a function in the Start Time and End Time boxes but it doesn't recognize my variables.

[image]

Comment: if the PowerApp has access to the SharePoint then why can't it create the list item directly on the vacation calendar? Why is a flow needed?